# onclick Button is calling the wrong array of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, onclick

***Functionality:***

Originally, when user enters a page, a list of randomised image is displayed. However, when user clicks on button A,  the list of randomised image will be displayed in accordance to the specific category, it will therefore show only a handful of randomised images from the main list.

Therefore, if the main list has got 10 images, and when user clicks on buttonA that is categorise as fruits, the resulting image would only show images that are categorise as fruit. Hence, it would result in just 6 fruits images being displayed. The other 4 images that are not fruits will not be displayed.

***What has been done:***

I have created 2 arrays: 1st array is for the main list of images and the 2nd array is the category array: fruits.

Secondly, I have created a randomised function for the first array and the second array.

I have attached the code for your perusal:

```js
var slideDuration = 1200;
var idleTime = 0;

//MainImageArray
var MainNameArray = ["http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg", "http://loremflickr.com/g/320/240/paris,girl/all", "http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg", "http://loremflickr.com/g/320/240/paris,girl/all", "http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg", "http://loremflickr.com/g/320/240/paris,girl/all", "http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg", "http://loremflickr.com/g/320/240/paris,girl/all", "http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg", "http://loremflickr.com/g/320/240/paris,girl/all"]

//Fashion Array
var FruitArray = ["http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg", "http://loremflickr.com/g/320/240/paris,girl/all", "http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg", "http://loremflickr.com/g/320/240/paris,girl/all", "http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg"]


$(function() {
  //Auto populate into brand container once randomised for each Brand image
  var MainNameArrayBackup = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MainNameArray));
  for (i = 0; i < $('#list').find('img').length; i++) {
    //To Set random Brand
    var random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * MainNameArray.length);
    //Assign Variable to generate random Brands
    var Brand = MainNameArray[random_BrandIndex];
    MainNameArray.splice(random_BrandIndex, 1);
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).attr('src', Brand);
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).show();
    console.log(Brand);
  }
  MainNameArray = MainNameArrayBackup; //re-assigning values back to array
});

function Fruit() {
  //Auto populate into brand container once randomised for each Brand image
  var MainNameArrayBackup = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(FruitArray));
  for (i = 0; i < $('#list').find('img').length; i++) {
    //To Set random Brand
    var random_FruitIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * FashionArray.length);
    //Assign Variable to generate random Brands
    var FruitBrand = FruitArray[random_FruitIndex];
    FruitArray.splice(random_FruitIndex, 1);
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).attr('src', FruitBrand);
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).show();
    console.log(FruitBrand);
  }
  FruitArray = MainNameArrayBackup;
}
```

```css
.menu {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  opacity: 0.98;
}
.Container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  width: 1260px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.innerScroll {
  position: relative;
  width: 1250px;
  height: 600px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #8d8989 !important;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#Fruit {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 362px;
  left: 1548px;
  z-index: 9;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="ChooseBrand" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1920px; height:1080px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display:none; z-index=3; top:0px; left:0px;">

  <input type="text" id="SearchField" style="position:absolute; top:190px; left:660px; height:40px; width:600px; outline=0px; border: 0; font-size:25px; font-family:'CenturyGothic'; background: transparent; z-index=4;" autofocus src="lib/VivoCity/img/transparent.png">
  <div class="Container">
    <div id="list" class="innerScroll">
      <!--1st Row-->
      <img id="Brand_1" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:0px; border:0px; outline:0px" data-brand="1">
      <img id="Brand_2" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:330px; border:0px;" data-brand="2">
      <img id="Brand_3" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:650px; border:0px;" data-brand="3">
      <img id="Brand_4" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:965px; border:0px;" data-brand="4">

      <!--2nd Row-->
      <img id="Brand_5" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:0px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('5');">
      <img id="Brand_6" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('6');">
      <img id="Brand_7" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('7');">
      <img id="Brand_8" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('8');">

      <!--3rd Row-->
      <img id="Brand_9" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:0px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('9');">
      <img id="Brand_10" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('10');">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="Fruit" onclick="Fruit()"></button>
</div>
```

***Issue:***

At this point in time, when I clicked The Fruit Button, all 10 images are displayed and not the correct amount of images as stated within the Fruit array is displayed.

Hence, the correct behaviour is that when user enters the page, they will see a randomised 10 images, and when they clicked on the fruit button. It will only show 5 images from the fruit array.

Therefore, what could have possibly done wrong?

Please help. thank you.

Comment: Your function is called Fruits but your on click is Fruit -- Is this just mistyped in your code here? Are you sure you are actually calling your Fruits method?

Comment: @Brian, sorry, is just a mistype here in the jsFiddle. the code itself is still Fruit()